# How do I color a hexagonal grid such that it doesn't have neighbors of the same color?

Tags: javascript, hexagonal-tiles

I have a javascript app that generates a hex grid. Each hex is pointy topped with three variables for each of the cube coordinates (x, y & z). I also have an array with three hex sprites.

I've tried `sprite = sprites[hex.x&3]`, which produces neat rows of hexes. I have also tried to offset the rows depending on the column via `sprite = sprites[(hex.x + hex.y&3)&3]` but that didn't work. I'm currently fiddling with the formula with little success.

I know for a fact that I need no less than three sprites to do this, but I can't find a way to combine the three cube coordinates to show the correct sprite on the array :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a hex grid you'll need three colors to color each hex so that it doesn't have the same color as a neighbor:
[image: Hexagonal grid with three colors so that colors never match their neighbor]

You were on the right track with your solution. Instead of adding `x+y` you'll want to subtract `x-y`. The other change is that `&3` is for bit manipulation; you'll want `%3` instead. However, in some languages, including Javascript, `%3` can return a negative number, so you'll need to use `((___%3)+3)%3` to make it positive.

The color/sprite id you want is `((x-y)%3 + 3) % 3`. I made [an interactive demo](https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1902-hexagon-coloring/) to test this.